# Execute a URL from AJAX page

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I'm looking for a method to execute a URL from an AJAX page.

The scenario is like im creating a bidding page with 3 products. Time limit is 5 second and after finishing 5 seconds, i wanted to insert the selected product details to database (this is why we need to execute a URL) and the loop should again start from 5 ..4..3..

The issue i'm facing right now is, i can not able to execute a url from this ajax call. I tried CURL; but this is not working.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});

test.php
--------
curlSession = curl_init();
```

// HERE I NEED TO EXECUTE THE URL

```
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.132/oxid/index.php?fnc=tobasket&aid=378442f7aa427425c741607aa3440ee8&am=1');
curl_exec($curlSession);
curl_close($curlSession);
```

Regards,
Tismon

Comment: More code or a better explanation is needed...

Comment: where is the ajax call?

Comment: not working **HOW**? you're not capturing the return value of `curl_exec()`, so if you're trying to fetch anything from that url, it's just being thrown away. Plus, if the exec fails, the return value would be a boolean FALSE, which you're also not checking for. As for ajax, that's not ajax. That's just PHP doing an HTTP request via HTTP. An AJAX call is done from a client browser back to a server.

Comment: Is there any error in Ajax call? `curlSession` without `$` seems to me error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and confirm if this solves your purpose:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'headers that you want to pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url/that/you/want/to/call');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Posted thinking that you need help on basic curl

For using Ajax, you should look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php).

Comment: Sadly this is not working. Can anyone tell me how do we call an external url without redirecting from a PHP page ?

Comment: edited my answer with a link to JQuery Ajax post that might help you